# Firestore query for a date field where the year does not matter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have birthdays as timestamp stored in my database. Now I wanted to create a fcm notification whenever a users birthday is approaching. I have a function running every hour to check for the birthday field, but what should I query for? Is there a fancy way of doing this where the year does not matter?

For example someone born on 02/27/1921 and someone born on 02/27/1991 both have their birthdays today.
But I cannot query 100 years in one query can I? I also could add another field which saves the birthday as year "0" so i could query for timestamps with todays date and year zero. But then I have to maintain and update the second field as I also need to keep the year to determine the age of the person.

Is there any easy solution?

Comment: Why don't you just store the dd/MM of the birthday as a string, or compute it on the fly to compare it to dd/MM of the current day ? I think there are some date functions in Firestore. And regarding year (to get user's age) you can probably also compute it on the fly from the birthday date.

Comment: Yah, but my problem is that if I want to compute it on the fly I would need to request ALL documents and that might be a few and that can cost. So I think I need to store the dd/MM as a string or timestamp with year fixed and maintain both fields. My question here is if i might miss API functions that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to query for just the month/day of timestamps in Firestore. In order for Firestore to meet its performance guarantees, all range queries need to return contiguous results, which isn't the case for this type of condition.

Rhe normal solution (and very common in NoSQL databases) is to modify your data structure to allow the use-case you want. So as AFract commented, you'll want to store the `MM/dd` as a string field, so you can query on that.

If you have existing data, you will indeed need to update each document, a process commonly referred to as *backfilling* the data. This too is quite common when working with NoSQL databases.

Comment: Ok. Thank you this answers it then. One more question as of regards to both of you speaking about string fields. Is the comparison of string more performant then the comparison of timestamps? Currently Birthday is stored as midnight on that day/year in the specific timezone the user lives in. If I store it as a string I also need the timezone saved. So imo it does make more sense to have two timestamp fields one with fixed year one with the real year (or the year just as single integer) - Is there anything wrong with my thought before refactoring this?. Thansk so far though

Comment: I don't think there's a significant enough performance difference for the comparison between types to matter when you're querying over a network. If you think there might be, it might be worth doing the comparison. If you do and there is a significant difference, definitely report back - or post a separate question and self-answer, because folks love learning such details.